# How to convert Google Map's "Embed map" link to "Share link"

Tags: php, google-maps

For example, here is a [test location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lexington,+KY/@38.0285169,-84.6119922,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88424429cc9ceb25:0x84f08341908c4fdd!8m2!3d38.0394389!4d-84.5013428).

If you press "**Share**" link - there is 2 tabs "**Share link**" and "**Embed map**"

**Share link**'s data:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lexington,+KY/@38.0279975,-84.751751,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88424429cc9ceb25:0x84f08341908c4fdd!8m2!3d38.0394389!4d-84.5013428
```

**Embed map**'s data:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d402280.8397603136!2d-84.75175098821046!3d38.02799750322416!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88424429cc9ceb25%3A0x84f08341908c4fdd!2sLexington%2C+KY!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1484200230503" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have only access to **Embed map**'s data. Is there a way I can change **Embed map**'s iframe's src to **Share link**'s src? Does anyone know what algorithm it uses?

Example: I want to change `"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d402280.8397603136!2d-84.75175098821046!3d38.02799750322416!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88424429cc9ceb25%3A0x84f08341908c4fdd!2sLexington%2C+KY!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1484200230503"` TO `"https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lexington,+KY/@38.0279975,-84.751751,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88424429cc9ceb25:0x84f08341908c4fdd!8m2!3d38.0394389!4d-84.5013428"` by PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DO you need the whole data? Cause this will work if you copy paste the link result in a browser.

```
$array = explode('=', $src);
$data = array_filter(explode('!', $array[1]));

$location = $x = $y = '';
foreach($data as $s)
{
    if(substr($s, 0, 2) == "2s" and strlen($s) > 5)
    {
        $location = substr($s, 2);
    }
    elseif(substr($s, 0, 2) == "3d" and strlen($s) > 5)
    {
        $x = substr($s, 2);
    }
    elseif(substr($s, 0, 2) == "2d" and strlen($s) > 5)
    {
        $y = substr($s, 2);
    }
}
if($location != "" and $x != "" and $y != "")
    $result = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/'.urldecode($location).'/@'.$x.','.$y;
else
{
    // parse error
}
```

Not perfect, but tested a little and it worked. The strlen is to prevent getting the other variables, because I'm not sure what they could be but the pattern sugests not being longer than 5 chars.